# How do I make a photoshop action pick a color from the image?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, actions

I am trying to capture a photoshop action that requires setting the foreground color by using the color picker at a particular location in the image.

When I record the action, a 'set foreground color' operation is recorded, but to a fixed color, the one I have just picked. I want the action to be something like "use picker to capture color at location (x,y)".

Is there any way to persuade Photoshop (either CS6 or CC) to record this sort of action?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a script which samples the 10,10 pixel location and sets the foreground color:

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument
var pixelLoc = [UnitValue("10 pixels") , UnitValue("10 pixels")];
var colorSamplerRef = docRef.colorSamplers.add(pixelLoc);
app.foregroundColor = colorSamplerRef.color
```

You can run the script as part of an action sequence.

Further reading google: "adobe photoshop scripting reference"

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for something instant, but I'll manage with the script. I'll use this scheme.

Comment: Note that it is possible to show a prompt for the pixel coordinates.

Comment: What modifications are needed in the script above for it to work in Photoshop CC 2014.2.1? Thanks, Jeff

Answer (score 1):

I've rewrote the code provided by Horitio so it'll work in newer versions of photoshop.

```
var docRef = app.activeDocument;
var pixelLoc = [32,42];
var colorSamplerRef = docRef.colorSamplers.add(pixelLoc);
app.foregroundColor = colorSamplerRef.color;
```

x = 32 and y = 42. Set this to whatever you need it to be.

Hint: Tap `f8` to figure out what the x and y location of your mouse are.

Comment: thank you for this script.
I tried pasting the script into Apples script editor, however photoshop wont let me select it. I know very little about scripting, so I was just wondering if I am missing an extra step? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you