# Creating an apple script for photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mac, osx

I am attempting to create an apple script which will automatically select a foreground colour from my current layer in photoshop.
I believe that this script is what I am looking for: [How do I make a photoshop action pick a color from the image?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/how-do-i-make-a-photoshop-action-pick-a-color-from-the-image/160723#160723).

However photoshop wont let me select the script, so I am not sure where I have gone wrong.

After I copy and paste this script into applescript, is there anything else that I need to add for it to work on the latest photoshop?

Comment: I believe you should run it from the apple  script editor

Comment: By the way, in the topic that you’ve linked the script is in JavaScript, not AppleScript.

Answer (score 2):

That script is **javascript** and not AppleScript. They are two separate, distinct, scripting languages. (Like French and Spanish.... many similarities, but still quite different)

In general, one should *not* use Apple's ScriptEditor unless you wish to control the operating system in some manner. AppleScript is used to control the *Apple operating system* and *Apple applications*.

Adobe applications all use javascript to control Adobe *applications*. While it *is* possible to control Adobe applications through AppleScript, the script has to be *written in the proper language* for any AppleScript to function. It is not possible to just paste a set of javascript commands into Apple's ScriptEditor and have a functional AppleScript.

At the *very least* any AppleScript would need to call that *javascript specifically within the AppleScript* to control Adobe applications. But using AppleScript can often be unwarranted overhead if the desire is to merely automate Photoshop.

**In short:** You *do not* really need or want AppleScript here. AppleScript is simply overhead given that you have a (presumably) functional javascript and are not seeking to control the Apple operating system in any way.

---

Copy the script to a **plain text** file.. save the text file with a `.jsx` suffix. *Then* Photoshop will see the script. Whether or not the javascript works as desired is another matter.
<sub>(**Important Note:** Apple's TextEdit, by default, will save *rich text*. That is **not** what you want. You want *plain text*. You can change the TextEdit preferences to save *plain text*.)</sub>

---

You can check the [*help files*](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/photoshop/using/scripting.html#:%7E:text=Choose%20File%20%3E%20Scripts%20%3E%20Script%20Events,run%20when%20the%20event%20occurs.) related to scripting Photoshop for more information.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you for your clear explanation, that worked!